# Diagonal lines on my background grid

Tags: interface

Does anyone know why my grid has diagonal lines in orthograpic view? I'm on 3.1

[image: Diagonal grid lines]

Comment: It's a camera view problem I think, your model is too big and has weird scale, look at the scale values in the top right of your interface. These should ideally be around 1, 1, 1

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue mine was fixed by changing the **Clip End to 10000** see image below.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

After changing the numbers:

[image: img3]

A good video that helps explains scaling in blender and how to set it up is https://youtu.be/VihRvil3138

If your working in Meters just adjust it.